# Unexpected results parsing date strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm working on a JavaScript application. I have two different String dates `31/10/2013`  and `1/11/2013` and I create an instance of these two dates with `new Date(string).getTime();`

But it shows this (the same date ) as the result:

```
console.log(date_s + " after new date " + date );

31/10/2013 after new date Fri Nov 1 00:00:00 UTC 2013

1/11/2013 after new date Fri Nov 1 00:00:00 UTC 2013
```

Comment: What's the point of getting the time of dates you just created with NO TIME ?

Comment: "31/10/2013" and "1/11/2013" are not valid date strings. The equivalent correct strings should be "2013/10/31" and "2013/11/1". Constructing a `Date` object with either of your strings results in an invalid date, and calling `getTime` results in `NaN`.

Comment: To clarify the comment from @JamesAllardice, [it might work sometimes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-[15.9.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)): "The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats." That is, to clarify further: it might work for the OP, but it's not a standard universal behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`31/10/2013` is not a valid date string unless you've got maybe some localization going on. To the default localization settings for en-US, it should be `10/31/2013`. What your string means is "month 31 of 2013" which pushes `new Date('31/10/2013')` to be some time in 2015 because that's where it resolves the date due to that "month 31."

Answer (score 1):

You haven't a valid string in you `new Date(string)`

Some example to initialize dates

```
var my_date=new Date(2013,10,31)
```

and all the documentation on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy solution, try [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) - a powerful javascript date parser/formatter/validator/manipulator.

In moment, you can parse date with the syntax like this [[doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)]:

```
//this will gives you a correct date object
moment('31/10/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate();
```

Else, you can always welcome to split and rebuild the date object.